# Get the last entry of a group SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have in my database 3 tables. One for the Apps, other for the historic of the state of the apps and a last table with the description of each state.

Table Apps:

```
ID   Name
1    App1
2    App2
```

Table Historic:

```
ID   IDApp  IDState  DateChanged
1    1      2        2016-06-01
2    1      4        2016-06-07
3    2      1        2016-06-05
4    2      2        2016-06-12
```

Table State:

```
ID  Description
1   Open
2   Working
3   Pending
4   Closed
```

I want a query that returns the last state of each App. I want the return like this:

```
Name   Description    Date
App1   Closed         2016-06-07
App2   Working        2016-06-12
```

Comment: So that's what you want, but what is your question? Or what have you done so far?

Comment: I've got that :   select apps.name, state.description, historic.DateChange from apps INNER JOIN historic ON apps.Id=historic.IdApp INNER JOIN state ON historic.IdApp=state.Id    That returns all the historic rows but I only want the last of each App and I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You should consider making your DateChanged field a date/time field if there can be multiple possible states witnessed for a given app on a single day.  As-is this should work but state reporting for a given app for a given day will arbitrarily choose the status with the highest ID if there are > 1 status witnessed for a given app on a the most recent day reported in history.

```
SELECT a.Name, 
    COALESCE(s.Description, '(No History)') as Description, 
    h.DateChanged as Date
FROM Apps a LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT IDApp, 
        MAX(IDState) as IDState, -- arbitrary tie breaker for > 1 state in a day
        DateChanged
    FROM Historic h1 INNER JOIN (
        SELECT IDApp, MAX(DateChanged) as MaxDateChanged
        FROM Historic
        GROUP BY IDApp
    ) h2 ON h1.IDApp = h2.IDApp
        AND h1.DateChanged = h2.MaxDateChanged
    GROUP BY IDApp, DateChanged
) h ON a.ID = h.IDApp
LEFT JOIN State s ON s.ID = h.IDState
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Name, Description, MAX(DateChanged) from Apps 
INNER JOIN Historic ON Apps.ID=Historic.IDapp 
INNER JOIN State ON State.ID=Historic.IDState 
GROUP BY Name, Description
```

Comment: with that query, the return is all the rows. I only want the most recent entry of the historic table for each app.

Comment: I have to receive only one line for each app